# Google GCP container-optimized OS - no space left during docker-compose build

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

1. I deleted everything with docker

- all images (dangling and not)
- all volumes
- i did system prune
- no conainters running

`docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

`docker images -a`

```
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE
```

`docker system df`

```
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          0         0         0B        0B
Containers      0         0         0B        0B
Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B
Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B
```

Im doing `docker-compose build php` which is just simple:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev libxml2-dev zip unzip mc git supervisor
#    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
#    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql pcntl soap mbstring exif

#RUN docker-php-ext-configure pcntl --enable-pcntl

RUN pecl install xdebug-2.6.0 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

[image: response]

Obviously everything worked fine before, i had to rebuild the image. I have free space available:
`df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       2.0G  1.2G  819M  59% /
devtmpfs        7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.9G  360K  7.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           7.9G  112K  7.9G   1% /etc/machine-id
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /tmp
tmpfs           256K     0  256K   0% /mnt/disks
overlayfs       7.9G  112K  7.9G   1% /etc
/dev/sda8        12M   24K   12M   1% /usr/share/oem
/dev/sda1        16G  8.4G  7.4G  54% /mnt/stateful_partition
tmpfs           1.0M  116K  908K  12% /var/lib/cloud
```

But first question, where's `/cache` mounted on google gcp? how can i clear it? since there's no directory like this.

`cd /cache`

`-bash: cd: /cache: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

Container-optimized OS is meant to be used to run containerized workloads, not to develop.

If you need to build your custom containers before you run them in compute instances, Container-optimized OS (CoreOS) is not the most flexible or comfortable option.

- Use whetever OS you find comfortable to work with.
- Publish the docker images to a container registry (there's a Google Container Registry for that).
- Run the containers *inside* container-optimized OS (they have the quickest startup time in GCP, usually <1 second).

Anoyther option is to use the Cloud Build service from Google to build and publish the containers for you (see https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers), then run the containers using Container-optimizerd OS.

Comment: Well, it is a production, but I had to rebuild my php container. 2nd: code is in git repository, not in the image, so I guess putting my containers into registry isn't an option. But anyway, how do I fix my problem at this point? I made a new machine from scratch and it  run, but this one is problematic

Comment: and I am running my containers inside - i mean, i have my docker-compose file to manage my containers. Most of  them is just clean docker images, but php i had to modify a bit, so I have a dockerfile for it. Is there a way to clean that /cache to re-run build then, or I had to create a new machine?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that 8gb of free disc space was too little to run build. I freed some space - that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your server doesn't have enough space to store the files that were generated by the docker build.

To verify if you have still had enough space in your server you may try to run the following command which displays your server available space.

> df -h

Using disk usage command and type the following command. You may see the highest folder will be at the top of the lists.

> sudo du -d1 -h /var/lib/docker | sort -hr

Make sure to stop all running docker containers before running the following command on your server.

> docker image prune --all

or

> docker image prune -a

This command will remove all unused images and all dangling images.

Double check your storage space using the **$ df -h** command and check if you have enough space already.

After running the command you will reclaimed new storage space again. You may now start your

> docker-compose up -d --build

Regarding your question on cache, Cache is not mounted on Google GCP. We need to create a path for the cache store for a particular application.

Local SSDs are suitable only for temporary storage such as caches, processing space, or low value data.
Refer the document on how to [Formatting and mounting a local SSD device](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd#gcloud).